# Problems resetting MySQL root password

Tags: mysql, password-recovery

I'm trying to reset the root password of my MySQL installation (yep, password forgotten) according to this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows.

But I keep getting an error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Of course I first stopped mysqld:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some INNODB file are stil open, try disabling antivirues or reboot.

Comment: Hey thanks! I restarted Windows and tried again, I got another (minor important) error (warning?) and restarted MySQL and my password is changed. Thanks a lot